# DownloadStringAsync return error , download file using url

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

when i am using a DownloadStringAsync with webclient its give me error how to solved this problem

```
 private  void BtnDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
               //string PDFPath = ((((sender as Button).Content) as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBlock).Text;
               string PDFPath = "http://www.ncu.edu.tw/~ncu25352/Uploads/20131231103232738561744.pdf";
               pdffile = PDFPath;

               WebClient wb = new WebClient();
               wb.DownloadStringCompleted += wb_DownloadStringCompleted;
               wb.DownloadStringAsync(PDFPath,"pdfnamefile");
    }

    void wb_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: `its give me error` Very useful explanation....

Answer (score 2):

First, you should give us the exact error.

This answer will assume you get the `NotImplementedException`.

You are getting this error because you auto-generated the `wb_DownloadStringCompleted` handler and didn't removed the `throw` clause.

Therefore, as soon as the download complete, you are yourself firing a `NotImplementedException`. Chances are that everything is in fact fine.

Try this code :

```
void wb_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //What you want to do
}
```

And add your instructions, of course.